# set a textview from any class

Tags: java, android

what i would like to do is be able to write to my textview from any other class. It might be simplistic and reveal my scripting background but my mainactivity class looks like

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        tv.DoIt("i love you");
        DoStuff(7);  // how many secs between alarms

  }
```

and i have written another little class that all i am trying to do is set the textview but the mainactivity wont compile

```
public class tv extends Activity{
TextView textElement;
public void DoIt(String zzmsg)
{
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    TextView textElement = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.affirmation);
    textElement.setText(zzmsg);
}
 }
```

Comment: tv is a activtiy class and you have  `tv.DoIt("i love you");` wrong. Read the docs. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html. You need to have textview in ManinActivity and you can use intent to pass values between activities and set text to textview in MainActivity

Comment: you have to create a tv object, then you can call `tv.DoIt("i love you");` another thing "am not a expertise in Android" but i think tv class should not be `extends Activity`

Comment: my problem is i have a repeating alarm in another class that i want to have different msgs for every alarm and i cannot return to mainactivity until after the msgs, so i need to do the textviews within the repeating alarm class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this code:

change onCreate...

```
private View mMainView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
    super.onCreate(arg0);
    mMainView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_app_share, null);
    setContentView(mMainView);
}

public void fillTextView(View view,int resId, String text)
{
   TextView textElement = (TextView) view.findViewById(resId);
   textElement.setText(text);
}
```

call function:

```
fillTextView(mMainView,R.id.affirmation , "i love you");
```

Comment: thanks Ahmad, i put the fillTextView in my MainActivity and tried to call the function from another method in another class and it came up with the non-static method cannot be called from a static class error - i am sorry i am trying to understand

Comment: ok i got it to compile by putting it in external class and it runs but no result

Comment: any more help please Ahmad?

Comment: i can't understand where use this code?
i think there is better way for solving your problem

Answer (score 0):

You should not be accessing a view created in a different activity like this. Also, why is the need to do this because only 1 activity would be shown at a time (either tv or mainactivity).

If you want to set something in another activity you should be using intents.

Comment: it is not that i want to create another activity but i could not use TextView unless it was an activity. i do most of the method in another class and after everything i wanted to write to the textview.. i cant figure out how to do that from mainactivity.